# error code for delete operation response

Tags: php, laravel

What is the error code for a delete operation that doesn't return true e.g.

```
if($post->delete()) {
     return response()->json(['message' => 'successfully deleted'], 200);
} else {
    return response()->json(['message' => 'something went wrong', error_code_here);
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the response to activate the jQuery `.error` method?

Comment: I would've said if the dependency injection object doesn't exist, return a 404

Comment: Depends on what is going wrong. My safest bet would be 500 internal server error.

Comment: http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html pz see this link

Comment: It would be simply your generic error code with the general error messages.  As you have shown generic error message. I would say you can go with status code 422 Unprocessable Entity : The request was well-formed but was unable to be followed due to semantic errors or as @Jerodev said you can use 500 interval server error which is also correct.

Comment: Yeah I did use a 422 and was trying to avoid a 500 because my app outputs in chained format for page errors, so I was trying to use an error that I could out put to the local function instead of the globals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the error handling code is not there, Laravel returns an `HTTP 500` error, regardless of the specific error thrown in the code.

> E.g. abort(403) would return a 500 error.